# Unable to open a file from PHP using fopen

Tags: php, file, fopen

i am trying to read contents from a text file in php. i am using wamp on windows. i m getting this error:

Warning: fopen(/input.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\cycle_gps_sender.php on line 3

this is my code:

```
$location = fopen("/input.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
echo $location;
fclose($location);
```

both the php file and input.txt are placed in www folder of wamp.

Comment: try to use full path of your file. if it still cannot be opened, it should be the permission problem.

Comment: Also, if the .txt file is in the same directory of your PHP file, remove the `/` or just do parent directories. I've had similar problems and it was cause it didn't know what the `/` was. Hope this helps.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to open stream : No such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 2):

Hope this will help you:

```
$File = "log_post.txt"; 
$fh = fopen ($File, 't') or die("can't open file");  
fclose($fh);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$location = fopen("input.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
echo $location;
fclose($location);
```

Use this code and keep the `input.txt` file in the same directory where this code is written.

Comment: There is a troubleshooting checklist for this error : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory

Answer (score 0):

First check if file [exist](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) or not?

```
 $filename = '/path/to/foo.txt';

if (file_exists($filename)) {
    chmod($filename, 0777);
    echo "The file $filename exists";
} else {
    echo "The file $filename does not exist";
}
```

Comment: There is a troubleshooting checklist for this error : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory

Answer (score 0):

```
$location = file_get_contents('./input.txt', FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);
echo $location;
```

or

```
$location = file_get_contents('input.txt');
echo $location;
```

hope it will help

Comment: There is a troubleshooting checklist for this error : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory

Answer (score 0):

Add full path to file.
On the Windows platform, be careful to escape any backslashes used in the path to the file, or use forward slashes.

```
$location = fopen("C:\\folder\\input.txt", "r");
```

Comment: There is a troubleshooting checklist for this error : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory

Answer (score 0):

**Remove** **'/'**(Slash)

```
$location = fopen("input.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
```

Comment: There is a troubleshooting checklist for this error : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory

Answer (score 0):

```
$file = fopen("path/input.txt","a+") or die("Unable to open file!");
.....
fclose($file);
```

You have to create file before you READ or if you open file by 'r' , so if you open file by 'a+' , your file will be created automatically.

Answer (score 0):

first.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="prviProvera.php" method="POST">
        Satnica <input type="number" name="satnica" id="satnica" placeholder="Unesite satnicu" step="100"><br><br>
        Datum početka <input type="date" name="datumPocetka"><br><br>
        Datum kraja <input type="date" name="datumKraja"><br><br>
        <button type="submit" name="dugme">Izračunaj zaradu</button><br>
    </form>

    <?php
        if(isset($_POST["dugme"])){
            if(isset($_POST["satnica"]) && isset($_POST["datumPocetka"]) && isset($_POST["datumKraja"])){
                $satnica=$_POST["satnica"];
                $pocetak=$_POST["datumPocetka"];
                $kraj=$_POST["datumKraja"];
                if(date_create($pocetak)<=date_create($kraj)){
                    setcookie("satnica",$satnica,time()+60,"/");
                    setcookie("pocetak",$pocetak,time()+60,"/");
                    setcookie("kraj",$kraj,time()+60,"/");
                    echo "Cookies su postavljeni.";
                }
                else{
                    echo "Datum pocetka mora biti pre datuma kraja";
                }
                
                
            }
            else{
                echo "Niste popunili sva polja";
            }
        }
    ?>

</body>
</html>
```

**firstcheck.php**

```
   <?php
        if(isset($_COOKIE["satnica"]) && isset($_COOKIE["satnica"]) && isset($_COOKIE["kraj"])){
            $satnica=$_COOKIE["satnica"];
            $pocetak=$_COOKIE["pocetak"];
            $kraj=$_COOKIE["kraj"]; 
            $pocetakDatum=date_create($pocetak);
            $krajDatum=date_create($kraj);

            $brojRadnihDana=0;
            while($pocetakDatum<=$krajDatum){
                $danUNedelji=$pocetakDatum->format("N");
                if($danUNedelji<=5){
                    $brojRadnihDana++;
                }
                $pocetakDatum->modify("+1 day");
            }
            $zarada=$brojRadnihDana*$satnica*8;
            echo "Zarada za ".$brojRadnihDana." radnih dana je ".$zarada." dinara.";
        }
        else{
            echo "Kolacici ne postoje, idite na stranicu <a href='prvi.php'>Racunanje zarade</a>";
        }
        
        
    ?>
```

**s2nd.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Prijava na konkurs za master studije</h1>
    <form action="drugi.php" method="POST">
        Ime: <input type="text" name="ime"><br><br>
        Prezime: <input type="text" name="prezime"><br><br>
        Smer: <select name="smer" id="">
            <option value="RT">RT</option>
            <option value="NRT">NRT</option>
            <option value="IS">IS</option>
            <option value="ELITE">ELITE</option>
        </select><br><br>
        Prosek: <input type="text" name="prosek"><br><br>
        <button type="submit" name="dugme">Pošalji</button><br>
    </form>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST["dugme"])){
        if(!empty($_POST["ime"]) && !empty($_POST["prezime"]) && isset($_POST["smer"]) && !empty($_POST["prosek"])){
            $ime=$_POST["ime"];
            $prezime=$_POST["prezime"];
            $smer=$_POST["smer"];
            $prosek=$_POST["prosek"];
            
            $putanja="datoteke/prijava_master.txt";
            $fajl=fopen($putanja,"a");
            $stringZaUpis=$ime."#".$prezime."#".$smer."#".$prosek."\n";
            echo $stringZaUpis;
            fwrite($fajl,$stringZaUpis);
            fclose($fajl);
            header("Location: drugi2.php");
            exit;
            
        }
        else{
            echo "Popunite sva polja!";
        }
    }
?>

</body>
</html>
```

**2nispos.php**

```
<body>
    <?php
        if(file_exists("datoteke/prijava_master.txt")){
            $fajl=fopen("datoteke/prijava_master.txt","r");
            
            while(($red=fgets($fajl))!=NULL){
                $tmpNiz=explode("#",$red);
                echo "<div style='background-color:red; margin:5px; padding:10px; font-size:1.4rem;'>Ime: ".$tmpNiz[0].", Prezime: ".$tmpNiz[1].", Smer: ".$tmpNiz[2].", Prosek: ".$tmpNiz[3]."</div>";
            }
            fclose($fajl);
            echo "Vrati se na stranicu za popunjavanje <a href='drugi.php'>forme</a>";
        }
        else{
            echo "fajl ne postoji, idite na stranicu <a href='drugi.php'>Prijava studenata</a>";
        }
       
    ?>
</body>
```

**3rd.php**

```
<body>
    <h1>Stranica za prijavu</h1>
    <form action="treci.php" method="POST">
        Ime: <input type="text" name="ime"><br><br>
        Prezime: <input type="text" name="prezime"><br><br>
        Lozinka: <input type="password" name="lozinka"><br><br>
        <button type="submit" name="dugme">Prijavi se</button>
    </form>

    <?php
        
        if(isset($_POST["dugme"])){
            if(!empty($_POST["ime"]) && !empty($_POST["prezime"]) && !empty($_POST["lozinka"])){
                session_start();
                $_SESSION["ime"]=$_POST["ime"];
                $_SESSION["prezime"]=$_POST["prezime"];
                $_SESSION["lozinka"]=$_POST["lozinka"];
                $_SESSION["brPoseta"]=0;
                header("Location: profil.php");
            }
            else{
                echo "Morate popuniti sva polja";
            }
        }
    ?>

</body>
```

**functionfor3rd.php**

```
<?php
function ispis(){
    $ime=$_SESSION["ime"];
    $_SESSION["brPoseta"]++;
    
    echo "Dobrodošao/la, ".$ime."<br><br>";
    echo "Broj poseta: ".$_SESSION["brPoseta"];
}
?>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).